# JavaFx - webview not loading few parts of website

Tags: javafx, javafx-webengine

I am trying to load **https://www.paytm.com** and search some products in webview but facing following problems in it.
1.It is not loading images in home page
2.If I search any products in search box window is getting stuck and not giving any results
3.if I click any product link, in status bar it showing as finished but nothing is displayed/rendered in page

```
 private void Pageload() {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
        }

        //now you can load the content:

        String url = makeUrl(textField.getText()) ;
        webView.getEngine().load(url);
        textField.setText(url);

    }
```

All other sites are working fine including google,gmail.
I am aware that the way I am creating trust manager to trust all is not a good practice, this is only for testing so I am doing it.

Comment: All that are you doing is fine, simple, javafx-webview don't support all elements from web. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340274/javafx-embedding-a-browser-other-than-available-webview-with-javafx and then you will answer yourself.

Comment: I used electron as alternative for JavaFx to create desktop based application https://electron.atom.io/.If some one is looking alternate try electron